# Access member of parent UIViewController from embedded UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, member

I have a `UIViewController` VC opened modally.

This viewcontroller, built with a storyboard, contains a navigation bar and a `container view`.

The container view embeds a `UIPageViewController`.

The UIPageViewController has its own class.

From this class I need to access to a member of the parent UIViewController (OR, in my case it's the same, pass a value to the child view controller).

How to do it?

I tried to print out the `self.parent` and `self.presentingViewController` but it turns out their values are both `nil`.

I tried another thing too, but it's not performing very well: in UIViewController I refer to the child view controller this way:

```
var pVC = self.childViewControllers[0] as! PageViewController
```

this way I can pass a value to the pageViewController:

```
pVC.myVariable = "Blue"
```

but I can read it only in `viewDidAppear`, not in `viewDidLoad` (and it's slow).

I even tried to do a similar thing in the context of a `didSet`: it works way better but I don't know if this is very othodox.

Answer (score -1):

Do not set values or variables in `UIViewController` class. Make an `Initializer` of `PageViewController` and pass the values from another you want to change. Also, make some convenience initializers according to your need. This is the best practice. Do stuff of any class in the class itself.

Can you paste code? so that i can give exact solution what you want achieve.

Comment: There's practically no code, I made about anything with a storyboard, as explained above

Comment: I suppose the PageViewController is initialized when you embed it with a storyboard, so, if I understand well what you say, I can't add a custom initializer to its class if I can reference it from the "embedding" viewController

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315404/custom-init-for-uiviewcontroller-in-swift-with-interface-setup-in-storyboard