# how to prepare a segue when the destination needs initalising

Tags: ios, swift, segue

i am using a third parties View controller that needs to be initialised.

I am currently launching it programtically througbh a modal. It requires you pass
it a UIImage to initiated the controller.

Currrently i am doing as follows

```
let thirdPartyVC = ThirdPartyViewController(image: myUIImage)



 present(photoEditViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What i would like to do to do this with segues instead but i cant seem to work out how 
 to initialise the controller with the image.

Currently i am trying to make a ThirdPartyViewController in the storyboard.

i am then performing a segue to it and trying to set the image in prepare for segue as follows bellow.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       operformSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToThirdPartyVc", sender: Any?) 


    }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        switch segue.identifier! {
        case "segueToThirdPartyVc" :

             let destination = segue.destination as?  ThirdPartyViewControllerInstance

             destination.image = aUIIMage


        default:
        break

        }
```

Unfortunatly this is failing to initalise the controller. How do i sucessfuly init the controller.

Comment: First thing is that are you getting a compile time error or a run time error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom init for UIViewController in Swift with interface setup in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315404/custom-init-for-uiviewcontroller-in-swift-with-interface-setup-in-storyboard)

Comment: Also, consider having a normal view controller be what you segue to, set up in your storyboard.  But then put the custom view controller inside it using a container view, programmatically added during the normal view controller's viewDidLoad()

Comment: how would you add it programmatically non modally in the container? Is it possible for it just to fill the container?