# How to subclass a UIViewController and add properties in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, properties, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I want to make a new kind of view controller in Swift that has an additional property that *must* be explicitly initialized. It doesn't make any sense for this property to be nil or have a default value and the controller will only be initialized programmatically. I tried defining it like this:

```
class MyController : UIViewController {
  var prop: Int
  init(prop: Int) {
    self.prop = prop
    super.init()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder?) {
    fatalError("don't serialize this")
  }
}
```

I tried running this but it crashed because `super.init()` tries to run the nib constructor which isn't defined, so I tried adding that:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
  super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

But now the compiler complains that `prop` isn't being initialized. And this is my question: **how can I initialize `prop` correctly here?** I don't want a default value, and anything I set will override the correct value that I set in the other initializer.

I kinda hacked around it by setting some default value in the nib init, but then having my first init do this

```
self.prop = prop
super.init()
self.prop = prop
```

But other than being really weird and ugly, that makes me worried that now it is possible to initialize my view controller from a nib and end up with the default value, which would be bad.

What is the correct and idiomatic way to do this in Swift?

Comment: How is the view controller to be created? Storyboard? Programmatically?

Comment: @picciano programmatically

Comment: Have you thought about a protocol instead of inheritance? It's much cleaner and seems to currently be the convention for adding properties to existing classes.

Comment: Alternatively, could the view controller pull in the data it needs rather than having it be set in the init function?

Comment: Initializers are good for programmatically created viewControllers, but for viewcontrollers created through storyboard [you're out of luck and have to work your way around it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400793/5175709)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point the view controller must be initialized by calling `init(nibName:bundle:)` or `init(coder:)`

Try this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var prop: Int

    init(prop: Int, nibName nibNameOrNil: String? = nil, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle? = nil) {
        self.prop = prop
        super.init(nibName:nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Crap, the problem is that my view controller doesn't subclass UIViewController directly, there's an intermediate that needs to run. I left it out of the question initially because I didn't think it mattered...

Comment: Might need to see that as well then. You should be able to just substitute  your subclass for the `UIViewController`, but generally I like to discourage subclassing in favor of Protocols. Most functionality you want to accomplish with a "base" view controller can really be done with Protocols. But that may be another question to post...

Comment: Actually, this did help me figure it out! The problem is that the superclass was calling `[super init]` rather than `[super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`. The first is just a convenience method for the second, but because of polymorphism it ended up calling the nib init in `MyViewController`, which I didn't want! Changing it the explicit second form ensures that this doesn't happen. I think I actually demonstrate this in my question by calling `super.init()`, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
class MyController: UIViewController {

    var prop: Int

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    init(prop: Int) {
        self.prop = prop
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me using Swift 4, UIViewController does not have `init(frame:)` and must call designated init method. I think you are thinking of UIView

Comment: But then I need to define init(frame:)?