# Way to pass data to another vc with segues without open var

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to avoid open variables when using segues (or not segues)?
Everybody saw code like this:

```
if segue.identifier == ListViewController.className()
    {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ListViewController

        var data: CategoryModel

        data = filteredData[indexPath.row]

        destinationVC?.passedData = data
    }
}
```

But in `ListViewController` now we have a var that open for access.

```
class ListViewController: UIViewController
{
    //MARK: - DataSource
    var passedData: CategoryModel?
```

Maybe exist way to avoid this?

I was thinking about dependency injection with `init(data: data)`, but how to initiate this vc right?

**Edited.**

Using segue it's not a main goal. Main is to make `var` `private`. If there exist nice way to not to use segues and push data private I will glad to know.

I was trying to use `init()` and `navigationController?.pushViewController(ListViewController(data: data), animated: true)` 
but
`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on line:

```
self.tableView.register(ListTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: ListTableViewCell.identifier())
```

Comment: These links might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315404/custom-init-for-uiviewcontroller-in-swift-with-interface-setup-in-storyboard

Comment: And this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually make Interface builder use a custom init for your view controller, it will always use `init?(coder:)`.
So the easiest way to pass data to your view controller is to use a non-private property.

But if you really don't want to use an `internal` or `public` var you can always try something with a Singleton or Notifications but I don't think it would be wise

Comment: Maybe I'm just bothering to make this variable private, but how does this affect the code's testability? It turns out any method can put anything there. This worries me. I do not like singletones, but I see that any deviation from segues only complicates the code.

Comment: I'm not sure testability is an issue here. If you're interested with testability and good architecture you may want to try Clean Swift or VIPER. And yes, I would use a var and keep the code simple

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so

```
class ListViewController {

    private var passedData: CategoryModel?

    private init () {
    }

    public convenience init (passedData: CategoryModel?) {
        self.init()
        self.passedData = passedData
    }
}
```

And in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` of your initial table view controller:

```
let data: CategoryModel = filteredData[indexPath.row]
let destinationVC = ListViewController(passedData: data)
self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I believe the goal is to make `passedData` private but still somehow use a segue.

Comment: @rmaddy is it impossible to make it let or private when use segue?

Comment: @Carpsen90 i have an error that `tableView` outlet is nil when `self.tableView.register(ListTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: ListTableViewCell.identifier())` after init.

Comment: Who is supposed to call the convenience initializer? And it doesn‘t compile incase you make the class derive from `UIViewController`. And `destinationVC` isn‘t used at all.

Comment: @Carpsen90 `let destinationVC = ListViewController(passedData: data)` unused. perform just takes identifier.

Comment: It‘s not using segues anymore, which the question is about.

Comment: @Fabian if there is now way to make it private i'll glad to see how to make it right.

Comment: @IgorKandaurov The problem is that on segue the vc is initialized from storyboard, which uses `required init(coder:)`, so you can‘t pass things in through the initializer. If you can‘t put it through the initializer, then you have to give sb outside ability to set sth on it later if the vc requires data. You can do it with a setter, maybe one which works only once else throws, or with a public variable as usual. Or have a singleton which the vc can ask for data. Or use some kind of notification system. If you avoid segues, you can construct programmatically like Carpsen or use a factory nethod

Comment: @Fabian I'll glad to use factory method, maybe you have something to read about it?

Comment: @IgorKandaurov The idea is to construct the vc from a `UIStoryboard` instance, set data on it and then return the vc and present it as you want (means you can‘t use it with segues). You can make the factory method `static func make(data: MyData) -> MyVC` public and leave the formerly-public variable on the vc fileprivate/private, so only the factory-method residing in the same file/same class can set it.