# How to properly initialise a Codable struct in the ViewController without third-party frameworks?

Tags: swift

I have been trying to initialise a `Codable` struct using storyboard on the ViewController but it doesn't work.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Here's what I tried on View Controller:

```
var images: ImageRequest

init(images: ImageRequest)
{
    self.images = images
}
```

Code error above:

> Error: 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UIViewController'

```
init(images: ImageRequest)
{
    self.images = images
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Code error above:

> 'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

```
init(images: ImageRequest)
{
    self.images = images
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

The code above crashes. Error message:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented

Here's what I tried on the Struct:

```
public struct ImageRequest: Codable {
    public var albumId: Int
    public var id: Int
    public var title: String
    public var url: URL
    public var thumbnailUrl: URL

    public init( albumId: Int, id: Int, title: String, url: URL, thumbnailUrl: URL) {
        self.albumId = 0
        self.id = 0
        self.title = ""
        self.url = URL(string: "")!
        self.thumbnailUrl = URL(string: "")!
    }
}
```

```
public struct ImageRequest: Codable {
    public var albumId: Int
    public var id: Int
    public var title: String
    public var url: URL
    public var thumbnailUrl: URL

    public init( albumId: Int, id: Int, title: String, url: URL, thumbnailUrl: URL) {
        self.albumId = albumId
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl
    }
}
```

Comment: “The code above crashes." Any error message when crashing? What you are trying to do in fact, is how initialize a ViewController inside a Storyboard with a custom parameter, no? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315404/custom-init-for-uiviewcontroller-in-swift-with-interface-setup-in-storyboard

Comment: Yes. That's the error message: Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented.  I need to use that struct model in the ViewController, which will receive data from the api.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using storyboards and the method `init?(coder:` gets called when you try to create this view controller. And inside the `init?(coder:` you have given a fatal error that causes the error. You need to use the custom initializer that you have created and not use the storyboard provied `init?(coder:` initializer.

Here is the gist of code you need. But, you will have to make modifications to make it work according to your requirements.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var someProperty: String

    init(property: String) {
        someProperty = property
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

        view = viewController.view
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        someProperty = ""
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to use the custom initializer the Xcode complains as I mentioned in my post: Error: 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UIViewController'

Comment: I have added a small gist of code. But, it just a helper to understand how cumbersome it could get. Best case scenario would be to use the normal method of instantiating the VC and setting the required variables.

Comment: Indeed. It gets messy. I tried that code and gave me this error: Property 'self.someProperty' not initialized at super.init call When you say normal method of instantiating the VC, which method do you mean that would work in my case? Thanks

Comment: You could remove that error by just providing a default value to your property. I have edited my code to fix that, I missed that line. I have given the method to use to instantiateViewController in the above solution. Use that method in the other VC and set your property value.

Comment: It works if it string but the type is ImageRequest, and how will I give a default value to someProperty of type ImageRequest?

Comment: I also tried this:    var someProperty = ImageRequest(), but it gives this error: Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'

Answer (score 0):

A view controller in a storyboard is always initialized with `init?(coder:)`. You can't pass any parameters to that initializer other than the `coder` that iOS passes.

So, you're going to have to devise another method to initialize `images`. Possible options

1. Initialize it in `init?(coder:)`.
2. Declare it as an optional and initialize it in `viewDidLoad()`
3. If the view controller is reached via segue, declare it as an optional and assign a value to it in the source VC's `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` method.

The method you choose is very much dependent on your app's architecture and on where the data for `ImageRequest` comes from.